# Welche Dialektwörter werden im Standarddeutschen am meisten vermisst?

Tags: dialect, big-list, slang

Als ich zum Studium aus Österreich nach Berlin gegangen bin, habe ich einige Worte aus meinem Sprachschatz ersetzen müssen, da sie im Hochdeutschen nicht verstanden wurden. 
Einige der Worte habe ich sehr vermisst und dadurch etwas romantisiert.

Ein Beispiel für ein Wort:

> **heuer:**  [*dieses Kalenderjahr* oder *das gegenwärtige Jahr*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/heuer)
>   this year

Ein Beispiel für einen Ausdruck:

> **Das geht sich aus:** [*passen*, *klappen*, *(gerade noch) hinbekommen*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/was-bedeutet-das-geht-sich-nicht-aus)
>    It works out

Es wäre schön, hier eine Liste mit Worten/Ausdrücken aus verschiedenen Dialekten zu erstellen. Jedes der Worte wird in der Herkunftsgruppe häufig verwendet und muss bei Gesprächen mit Außenseitern ersetzt werden.

Ein Wort/Ausdruck pro Antwort mit Erklärung, Referenz und englischer Übersetzung. Dann können wir die einzelnen Antworten [aufwerten](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/998/ist-rauf-voten-und-runter-voten-eine-akzeptable-ubersetzung-fur-upvote-und/1003#1003) und ein Meinungsbild erstellen. Bin gespannt.

Sehr subjektive Frage, daher sollte es *community wiki* werden.

---

When I moved from Austria to Berlin for studying I had to replace some of my vocabulary. I missed these delicate words a lot and romanticised some of them.

It would be very interesting to learn about other commonly used dialect words which are incomprehensible in standard german. 
One word per answer including explanation, reference and English translation.

Subjective question, hence should become *community wiki*

Comment: @splattne: Das geht nur für Antworten, nicht Fragen.

Comment: Das Wort *heuer* wird aber durchaus in der Hochsprache verwendet, oder?

Comment: @splattne: Ja aber in anderer Bedeutung. Im Hochdeutsch ist die Heuer eine Bezahlung (meist für Seeleute).

Comment: @sl nicht wirklich, es kommt nicht häufig vor, ist aber durchaus gebräuchlich - z.B. Google ["ist heuer" auf Spiegel.de](http://www.google.de/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22ist+heuer%22+site:spiegel.de&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=e412b376bd18c81b&biw=1920&bih=955) - manche der Treffer sind alt, aber es sind auch aktuelle dabei.

Comment: Hochdeutsch?  Bundesdeutsch?  "Heuer" ist soweit ich weiss österreichische Hochsprache.  Also quasi im Össi-Duden (was ist eigentlich das Äquivalent zum bundesdeutschen Duden in A?).  So wie man in D "Januar" und in A "Jänner" sagt.  Kein Dialekt wie Bayrisch.

Comment: Keins von beiden ist Dialekt. "heuer" ist definitiv Hochsprache und "Das geht sich aus" ist Umgangssprache.

Comment: @Jürgen: Der Össi-Duden ist der Duden: er enthält durchaus auch österreichische Wörter (wie z.B. ["heuer"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heuer)).

Answer (score 8):

Im Südtiroler Dialekt, einer Variante, die dem Bayrischen ähnlich ist, gibt es die Möglichkeit, die Vorsilbe

**der-**

an gewisse Verben anzufügen. Dadurch ergibt sich der Sinn *"Es schaffen zu ..."*. Beispiele:

> derziachn: *"Der kloane Bua hat den schwaren Wogen alloan  derzochn."* ("Der kleine Junge schaffte es, den schweren Wagen alleine zu ziehen."
>
> derpacken: *"Sie hat die groaße Portion derpackt."* ("Sie schaffte es, die große Portion vollständig fertig zu essen.")
>
> derreden: *"Vor so vielen Leit' hat er's net gscheit derredt."* ("Vor so vielen Leuten konnte er nicht richtig sprechen.")
>
> derbremsen: *"Er hat's nimmer derbremst und isch in die Mauer g'fohrn."* ("Er schaffte es nicht mehr zu bremsen und fuhr in die Mauer.")

Die genannte Form nennt man in der Sprachwissenschaft übrigens *Aspekt (eines Verbs)*. In der Hochsprache ist die Verwendung des Aspekts nicht besonders ausgeprägt. Es gibt allerdings noch Spuren davon wie zum Beispiel im Wort *"[erraten](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/882/how-to-decide-whether-to-use-raten-or-erraten)"*.

Comment: der? hum, bei uns in salzburg ist das "da" :D

Comment: Oder angesichts der Vorbereitungen zum Festessen das Legendäre: Ob ma das dersch... werden?

Comment: I think this is the same as the Yiddish usage. "Schiessen emitzen" is to shoot someone, but "derschiessen" would be to shoot him dead. On the other hand, the "der-" prefix also replaces "er-" everywhere, so we have derziehung, derfahrung, etc. with the ordinary meanings.

Comment: I'm very glad to be participating in this excellent forum. I find most of the discussions to be fascinating; however, my own input will be mostly in comparing the nuances of Yiddish to those of Standard German. I appreciate your encouragement in this regard.

Comment: I might also mention that heu as in heu-jahriger is very much a Yiddish usage as well.

Comment: Häufig tritt auch der negative Aspekt ver- analog dazu auf (auch teilweise im Hochdeutschen): Etwas verraten, oder (im baierischen) sich verheben, ein Kind verziehen.

Comment: Das Schwäbische nutzt "ver" als Vorsilbe anstatt des bayrischen "der"

Answer (score 5):

Das bairische G'lump.

> das G'lump

Sammelbegriff für Dinge, die nicht ganz die Werbeversprechungen halten.
Kann auch auf Software angewandt werden, besonders wenn die Bedienbarkeit zu wünschen lässt.
In weiterem Sinne somit auf fast alles.

**Edit:**

es ist weniger abwertend als zu sagen

> es ist großer Mist

oder gar das "S-Wort" zu gebrauchen.

und weiter möchte ich euch das

> derblecken

nicht vorenthalten. siehe [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derblecken) und dabei eines der Meisters dieser Betätigung Walter Sedlmayr † 14. Juli 1990 gedenken.

Comment: Ist das nicht das gleiche wie der Klump und Plunder, den es in den 1€-Shops oiwoi gibt? Um nicht zu sagen Krempel.

Answer (score 5):

Ich vermisse im Hochdeutschen besonders das kleine sächsische Wort `mor`. Beispiel:

> Mor missn ma uffreim. (Wir müssen mal aufräumen.)

`mor` ist aber nicht nur das sächsische Wort für `wir`, sondern impliziert ebenfalls, daß die Tätigkeit nicht vom Sprecher sondern vom Adressaten ausgeführt wird. Hier also: `Du mußt mal aufräumen`.

Besonders kritisch wird es, wenn sich der Sachse an etw. stößt. Beispiel:

> Erwin hadssch an dor Dischgande gerammeld (Erwin hat sich an der Tischkante gestoßen)

Wenn man da nicht aufpaßt, erntet man schnell ungläubige Blicke!

Comment: +1 funny ;-)  Und das "Mor" gibt's im Badischen zumindest auch, als "Mir" (und wird auch gern als Synonym für Du benutzt... der Ton macht da die Musik)

Comment: Ist das *geil*! Das Sächsische hat im Laufe der Jahrhunderte erkannt, daß für diesen Fall ein eigenes Wort nötig ist. Davon können sich die anderen Dialekte noch ein Stück abschneiden! :)

Comment: 51% der hochdeutsch sprechenden Bevölkerung meint situationsabhängig das gleiche mit "wir". "**Wir** müssen **dann** mal den Müll runter bringen" heißt so viel wie "Bring (**Du**) **jetzt sofort** den Müll runter, aber flott!"

Comment: Was sagt die Frau zum Ehemann, der sich im Hochhaus in Selbstmordabsicht aus dem Fenster stürzt? "Nimm den Müll mit runter"

Answer (score 3):

Ein weiteres Beispiel:

> **sich abhauen**, Österreichisch für *sich kaputtlachen*,
>   to burst into laughter

Answer (score 3):

Ich vermisse das badische Wörtchen "als". In der Hochsprache wird es lediglich im Sinne von

- "Als ich ihn sah, wurde mir übel."
- "Ich bin schöner als du."

verwendet, aber im Süden hat es zusätzlich die Bedeutung von "manchmal", "ab und zu":

- "Ich hebb als e mol echt Luschd uff e Schnäpsle."
- "Früher war ich als öfter mol im Urlaub."

Comment: Sieht aber aus, als käme das 'manchmal' von 'e mol'(einmal) oder 'ab und zu' von 'öfter mol' (öfter mal), als sei das als also schlicht überflüssiger Ballast. Wirf's ab! :)

Comment: das ist mMn nicht "als", sondern "alls", als Abkürzung von vielleicht "allenfalls" oder  des Schweizer/Allemannischen "allfällig".

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always use the Bavarian

> Servus!

and

> Grüß Gott!

to give an unusual start to a conversation. People will instantly realize you're from Bavaria :-).

Comment: ... oder aus Österreich, gell Herr Kollege?   ("gell" find ich fantastisch)

Answer (score 1):

Auch wenn ich den Ausdruck nicht selbst verwende: Ich finde, dass der folgende bayerische Ausruf eine typische Dialektalform ist, die nicht genau in der Hochsprache wiedergegeben werden kann. Es ist als Ausruf so eine Art Mischung aus "oh!" und "aha!".

> **oha!**

mit den beiden Bedeutungen:

1. *Ausruf des Erstaunens*
2. *Halt-Kommando für Zugtiere*

Beispiel:

> Oha, du bist aber a gscheit's Dirndl!

Betont wird das Wort auf der ersten Silbe.

Comment: Und außerdem kann »Oha!« auch »Tschuldigung« bedeuten, wie in dem berühmten Witz vom Preußen auf der Wiesn … ;)

Answer (score 1):

From Cologne/Ripuarian dialect:

fimschich - Overly fussed/sensitive person erring on what could be described as "anal".

Der Fuss - A ginger.

Going to it extend the list later, but plenty of words which confuse non-rhenanians.

Answer (score 1):

Im Moselfränkischen gibt es das Wort *kloar*. Es bedeutet etwas zwischen *seltsam* und *komisch*, wobei *komisch* oft fälschlich verwendet wird, wo nur *befremdlich* gemeint ist.

Beispiel: Die Firma Olala verkauft ein kloares Gerät, dass wie ein Schneebesen aussieht, aber man stülpt es sich über den Haaransatz, und es löst ein gruseliges Kribbeln auf mechanischem Wege aus.