# Was bedeutet "heuer"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, meaning

Im Hochdeutschen gibt es diesen Ausdruck m. E. nicht, ich habe ihn allerdings schon öfter gehört ... was bedeutet er genau, wie wird er verwendet, wo kommt er her und wo wird er benutzt (Bsp.):

> heuer

Comment: siehe auch: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/welche-dialektworter-werden-im-standarddeutschen-am-meisten-vermisst

Comment: Österreichiche Wörter sind nicht per se kein Hochdeutsch. `Heuer`, `Kasten` (Schrank), `Paradeiser` (Tomate), `Obers` (Schlagsahne) usw. wird in ganz Österreich gesagt, und ist nicht Mundart oder Dialekt sondern Hochdeutsch.

Comment: +1, great word!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Heuer bedeutet „dies Jahr“. Man kann es mit *heurig* auch als Adjektiv verwenden.

Die folgenden Sätze haben dementsprechend alle dieselbe Bedeutung.

> Der heurige Sommer ist besonders heiß.
>
> Der Sommer heuer ist besonders heiß.
>
> Der diesjährige Sommer ist besonders heiß.
>
> Der Sommer in diesem Jahr ist besonders heiß.

Es gibt auch noch einige verwandte Begriffe, wie zum Beispiel *Heuriger*, was sowohl für den Wein des laufenden Jahres als auch für ein Weinlesefest oder ähnliche Veranstaltungen im Spätsommer oder Herbst stehen kann. Man sagt dann zum Beispiel, man geht zum Heurigen.

Comment: Alles richtig, nur die geographische Verbreitung fehlt. Die gibt es [hier](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_8/r8_f4d/index.html) zu sehen.

Comment: @WalterTross: Der Link funktioniert leider nicht mehr sinnvoll.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper hier ist die Karte wieder: https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r8-f4d-2/

Answer (score 16):

Eine andere Bedeutung von Heuer (hier großgeschrieben, weiblich, manchmal auch männlich) ist der Sold (das Gehalt) eines Matrosen oder Seemanns. Hieraus ist auch die Bedeutung von anheuern zu erklären.
Im Sinne von *Einkommen* taucht es auch in der bundesdeutschen Abgabenordnung (Steuerrecht) auf.

Comment: +1; hübsch beobachtet.

Answer (score 12):

"heuer" ist [Österreichisch für "dieses Jahr"](http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-287-heuer-dieses*Jahr.html).

Viele österreichische Ausdrücke gibt es genauso in Bayern, also stehen die Chancen gut, dass es auch Bayrisch ist.

Comment: Ja, der Begriff wird in ganz Bayern verwendet.

Comment: Wird auch oft in der Schweiz [verwendet](http://www.klartext.ch/?p=11848).

Comment: In Franken verwendet man das auch.

Comment: @cfaerber etc.: Österreich, Bayern, Franken, und teilweise Schweiz, sind [hier](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_8/r8_f4d/index.html) bestätigt

Answer (score 8):

Das Adverb *[heuer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heuer)* bedeutet "dieses Jahr / in diesem Jahr".

Zur Herkunft schreibt der Duden

> mittelhochdeutsch hiure, althochdeutsch hiuru, zusammengezogen aus: hiu jāru = in diesem Jahr

(Vergleiche

> mittelhochdeutsch hiute, althochdeutsch hiut(u), zusammengezogen aus: hiu tagu = an diesem Tage

für *heute*)

Der Duden beschreibt die Verbreitung des Wortes, und auch die des zugehörigen Adjektivs *[heurig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heurig)*, mit "süddeutsch, österreichisch, schweizerisch". Im Rahmen des Projekts "Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache" hat die Uni Augsburg eine [Karte zur Verbreitung des Wortes](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_8/r8_f4d/) erstellt. Die in München beheimatete, aber überregional erscheinende [*Süddeutsche Zeitung* benutzt es](http://suche.sueddeutsche.de/query/heuer) in den Rubriken "München" und "Bayern" regelmäßig, sonst gelegentlich. Ich kann es aus eigener Erfahrung auch für den erzgebirgischen Sprachraum bezeugen und als weitere Belege das Online-Archiv der in Chemnitz erscheinenden *[Freien Presse](https://www.google.de/search?q=heuer%20site%3Afreiepresse.de)* anführen und das Buch ["Erzgebirgische Dorfgeschichten"](http://books.google.de/books?id=XDCroBGYARYC&pg=PT203&lpg=PT203&dq=heuer%20erzgebirgisch&source=bl&ots=Yt9juGoM-h&sig=9uSb1ei66AkDYuCtHCKTDhdkruw&hl=de&sa=X&ei=VvFPVOf2B8H4OqScgZAC&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=heuer%20erzgebirgisch&f=false) von Karl May (!). [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erzgebirgisch#Sonstige_W.C3.B6rter) nennt dazu übrigens "heier" als Verschriftlichung; was ich von meinen Großeltern gehört habe, mag vom Klang her irgendwo in der Mitte gelegen haben, kam aber jedenfalls in hochdeutschen Sätzen daher (in Mundart hätte ich sie gar nicht verstanden).

Interessant ist auch ein Blick ins *[Deutsche Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH07979#XGH07979)* der Gebrüder Grimm. Zum einen wegen der Zitate von Uhland, Picander, Goethe, Kotzebue und Freiligrath (allesamt keine Bayern, Österreicher oder Schweizer), zum anderen auch wegen der Notiz

> im nhd. jetzt veraltend und in gewählter sprache gemieden

Das Adjektiv *heurig* scheint mir deutlich weniger gebräuchlich zu sein, es hat sich aber auf jeden Fall in der Redensart "kein heuriger Hase mehr sein" (d.h. Erfahrung haben) erhalten.

<s>Bemerkenswert erscheint mir auch, daß der Duden noch eine zweite Bedeutung des Wortes *heuer* vermerkt, nämlich "[in der heutigen Zeit, heutzutage](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heuer#Bedeutungb)". Dies war wohl mal so, jedenfalls nennen auch die Grimms diese Bedeutung, und ich glaube, daß ich eine solche Verwendung vom Kontext her auch richtig verstehen würde. Mir ist aber bei der Recherche nirgendwo auch nur ein einziges Beispiel dafür untergekommen, und das vom Duden angeführte erscheint mir reichlich dürftig.</s> **Update:** mittlerweile hat der Duden diese zweite Bedeutung offenbar entfernt.

Comment: Danke für die Herkunft, den Vergleich mit „heute“, die Verbreitung und das Fehlen von Propaganda.

Answer (score 4):

Ich möchte noch etwas zu den anderen Antworten ergänzen:

"heuer" ist, wie schon in den anderen Antworten nachgelesen werden kann, ein Austriazismus und bedeutet "dieses Jahr" (Zum Begriff "Austriazismus" siehe diese Frage: [Was genau ist ein "Teutonismus"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5387/was-genau-ist-ein-teutonismus))

Von "heuer" ist das Adjektiv "heurig" abgeleitet. "Heurig" bedeutet "diesjährig":

> Die heurigen Paradeiser schmecken fad. = Die diesjährigen Tomaten schmecken langweilig.

Bei zwei Agrarprodukten gibt es weitere Begriffe, die davon abgeleitet sind:

> Die Heurigen (Erdäpfel)

Dieses Wort ist ein Pluraletantum, das heißt, es gibt dieses Wort nur als Mehrzahl, nicht als Einzahl. Die Heurigen sind heurige Erdäpfel, also Kartoffeln, die dieses Jahr geerntet wurden. Gemeint ist damit eine bestimmte Erdäpfel-Sorte, die schon im Frühjahr (Frühling) geerntet werden, meist im Mai oder Anfang Juni.

> Der Heurige (Wein)

Dieses Wort ist ein Singularetantum, also eine Wort, das es nur in der Einzahl gibt. Damit ist Wein des heurigen Jahres gemeint, den man ab dem Spätherbst verkosten kann. Dieses Wort ist zwar ein ganz offizielles Wort des österreichischen Hochdeutsch, findet aber nur in den Weinbaugebieten Ostösterreichs Verwendung.

> Der Heurige, die Heurigen (Gastwirtschaft)

Von Heurigen (also dem heurigen Wein) abgeleitet ist das Heurigen-Lokal, das auch "der Heurige" heißt, wovon aber sowohl Einzahl als auch Mehrzahl existieren.
Ein Heuriger war ursprünglich eine temporäre Gastwirtschaft. Weinbauern durften für eine bestimmte Zeit im Herbst ihren heurigen Wein ausschenken und dazu einfache Speisen (Brot, Wurst, Schinken usw.) kredenzen. Heute werden in weiten Teilen Ostösterreichs mit "Heuriger" auch Lokale bezeichnet, die das ganze Jahr über offen haben dürfen, wenn sie in der Hautsache selbstproduzierten Wein und kalte Speisen anbieten.

Comment: Nice answer, I hope it gets lots of upvotes.

Comment: Keine der anderen Antworten behauptet, daß _heuer_ ein Austriazismus wäre (im Sinne von _ein Begriff, der nur in der Varietät "österreichisches Deutsch" Verwendung findet und außerhalb Österreichs entweder unbekannt ist oder als fremd empfunden wird_) - und es stimmt auch nicht. Siehe die Kommentare zur Antwort von Joachim Sauer, oder auch meine eigene Antwort.

Answer (score 2):

Wie schon in anderen Posts bemerkt, bedeutet "heuer" "dieses Jahr" und ist völlig analog zu verwenden wie "heute" für "der gegenwärtige Tag".

Die im Netz vereinzelt zusätzlich zu findende Bedeutung "heutzutage" kenne ich nicht und halte ich für grundsätzlich falsch. Genauso falsch finde ich es, "heuer" als Austriazismus zu bezeichnen - es wird wohl zumindest in ganz Bayern aktiv verwendet, und ich kann mich an keine Verständnisprobleme im süddeutschen Raum erinnern.

Wer den Begriff kennt, wird ihn in schriftlichen Dokumenten kaum als zu mundartlich vermeiden, sondern empfindet ihn eher als regional gefärbte Hochsprache - etwa so, wie man als Süddeutscher eher zu "reden" tendiert wo ein Norddeutscher "sprechen" benutzt würde.

Comment: Auch [der Duden kennt heutzutage "heutzutage"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heutzutage)...

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. D.h. also, da "heutzutage" korrektes Deutsch ist, ist "heuer" auch ein Austriazismus? Weil es wenig Rolle spielt, wo ich mit einem Wort verstanden werden, solange historisch belegt ist, wo das Wort entstanden und eingewandert ist.